# WCF XML nodes without namespace not serializing

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I'm integrating with third party webservice client the request looks like this:

```
<s:envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="https://example.com/wcf">
    <s:body>
        <ns:getdata>
            <ID>1</ID>
        </ns:getdata>
    </s:body>
</s:envelope>
```

and it's not parsed correctly, ID is null in my function:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "https://example.com/wcf")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void getdata(string ID);
}

public class Service2 : IService1
{
    public void getdata(string ID)
    {
        //ID is null
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include your deserialization code

Comment: Your datacontracts, give them to me